# Sum the grouped results in the template

Tags: 8, views

I have an aggregated view result grouped by taxonomy terms and shown like the following.

> TaxonomyTerm1
> 1
> 1
> TaxonomyTerm2
> 1
> TaxonomyTerm3
> 1
> 1
> 1

I want the result to be added and shown like the following.

> TaxonomyTerm1
> 2
> TaxonomyTerm2
> 1
> TaxonomyTerm3
> 3

I tried to calculate the result in views-view-fields--reports.html.twig file with the following code.

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for field in fields -%}
  {% set total = total + 1 %}
{%- endfor %}
{{ total }}
```

Instead of the expected result, I get the original values again.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem with using **View Aggregator Plus** module. These are the settings I used on *Views > View Aggregator Plus Module > Style > Settings*.

- For the taxonomy column

  1. In *Apply group functions* for the taxonomy column the result must be grouped by, select the *Group and compress* option
  2. In the *Render column* section, select the taxonomy column you want to shown as label
- For the total number column

  1. In *Apply column function*, select *Count (having regexp) **
  2. In the *Render column* section, select the title, for example as a field, because any field that repeats will be counted as total number with these options

To make it clearer, these are my fields.

- TaxonomyColumn (which is being grouped by)
- Title (the titles for the nodes with  the taxonomy column)

Most importantly, make sure the default aggregation is disabled. It is by default, since the *View Aggregator Plus* module provides many aggregation options.